# Do a sort with sails waterline on numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm facing a sorting problem on my sails application:

I'm trying to do sort using waterline on an object but it seems to be sorted as a string instead of an integer.

Here is my oject :

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    id:{
        type:"int", 
        required:true
    },
    id_scenario:{
        type:"int",
        required:true
    },
    id_commande:{
        type:"int", 
        required:true
    },
    ordre:{
        type:"int"
    }
  }
};
```

Here is my code:

```
ScenarioCommande.find()
    .where({ id_scenario: idScenario })
    .sort({ordre: 'ASC'})
    .exec(function(err, scenariocommande) {
    res.json(scenariocommande);
});
```

And here is the output:

```
{
    "id": "30",
    "id_scenario": "12",
    "id_commande": "6",
    "ordre": "1",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null
  },
  {
    "id": "37",
    "id_scenario": "12",
    "id_commande": "18",
    "ordre": "10",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null
  },
  {
    "id": "31",
    "id_scenario": "12",
    "id_commande": "4",
    "ordre": "2",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null
  },
  {
    "id": "23",
    "id_scenario": "12",
    "id_commande": "14",
    "ordre": "3",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null
  },
...
```

As you can see, these objects are sorted on the "ordre" parameter like it : 1, 10, 2, 3, like if this parameter was a string.

I tried many combinations but none worked. 
Have anyone an idea about it?

Thank you in advance!

Christophe

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake : my column "ordre" in my database was set to type varchar instead of integer.

Hope it helps someone!

Bye